# Why am i getting a NameError in this python code?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nameerror

I am currently on chapter 3 in the 'Python for Machine Learning' book. While, I am implementing the algorithms from the book, I got a NameError. I am not sure why I am getting this NameError, 'NameError: name 'X_combined_std' is not defined', when I had clearly defined the X_combined_std in line 54. Can someone tell me why I am getting a NameError and help me to fix it?

Error:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py:44: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)
Misclassified samples: 4
Accuracy: 0.91
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\qasim\Documents\python_machine_learning\scilearn.py", line 65, in <module>
    plot_decision_regions(X_combined_std, y_combined, classifier = lr, test_idx = range(105,150))
NameError: name 'X_combined_std' is not defined
[Finished in 2.2s with exit code 1]
```

Code:

```
    from sklearn import datasets 
import numpy as np
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, [2,3]]
y = iris.target 

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(X_train)
X_train_std = sc.transform(X_train)
X_test_std = sc.transform(X_test)


from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron 
ppn = Perceptron(n_iter = 40, eta0=0.1, random_state = 0)
ppn.fit(X_train_std, y_train)

y_pred = ppn.predict(X_test_std)
print('Misclassified samples: %d' % (y_test != y_pred).sum())

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))

from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def plot_decision_regions(X, y, classifier, test_idx=None, resolution = 0.02):
    #setup marker generator and color map 
    markers = ('s', 'x', 'o', '^', 'v')
    colors = ('red', 'blue', 'lightgreen', 'gray', 'cyan')
    cmap = ListedColormap(colors[:len(np.unique(y))])

    #plot the decision surface
    x1_min, x1_max = X[:, 0].min() -1, X[:,0].max() + 1
    x2_min, x2_max = X[:,1].min() - 1, X[:,1].max() + 1
    xx1, xx2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x1_min, x1_max, resolution), np.arange(x2_min, x2_max,resolution))
    Z = classifier.predict(np.array([xx1.ravel(), xx2.ravel()]).T)
    Z = Z.reshape(xx1.shape)
    plt.contourf(xx1, xx2, Z, alpha = 0.4, cmap = cmap)
    plt.xlim(xx1.min(), xx1.max())

    #plot all samples
    for idx, cl in enumerate(np.unique(y)):
        plt.scatter(x=X[y==cl,0], y = X[y == cl, l], alpha = 0.8, c=cmap(idx), marker = markers[idx], label = cl)

    #highlight test samples
    if test_idx:
        X_test,y_test = X[test_idx,:], y[test_idx]
        plt.scatter(x_test[:,0], X_test[:, 1], c='', alpha = 1.0, linewidths = 1, marker = 'o', s = 55, label = 'test set')

    X_combined_std = np.vstack((X_train_std, X_test_std))
    y_combined = np.hstack((y_train, y_test))
    plot_decision_regions(x=X_combined_std, y = combined, classifier = ppn, test_idx = range(105,150))
    plt.xlabel('petal length [standardized]')
    plt.ylabel('petal width [standardized]')
    plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
    plt.show()

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 
lr = LogisticRegression(C=1000.0, random_state = 0)
lr.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
plot_decision_regions(X_combined_std, y_combined, classifier = lr, test_idx = range(105,150))
plt.xlabel('petal length [standardized]')
plt.ylabel('petal width [standardized')
plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
plt.show()

weights, params = [], []
for c in np.arange(-5,5):
    lr = LogisticRegression(C=10**c, random_state = 0)
    lr.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
    weights.append(lr.coef_[1])
    params.append(10**c)
weights = np.array(weights)
plt.plot(params, weights[:,0], label = 'petal length')
plt.plot(params, weights[:,1], linestyle = '--', label = 'petal width')
plt.ylabel('weight coefficient')
plt.xlabel('C')
plt.legend(loc = 'upper left')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You didn't define `X_combined_std` or `y_combined`.

Comment: Sorry, I did not stated my full code here.

Comment: Heck, you didn't define `X_train_std` or `y_train` in what you've shown us, either. We need a [mcve].

Comment: You're missing code. Why do you not get an error on `X_train_std`? How can we understand the error if the code is not representative?

Comment: You don't need to show the full code, but a [mcve]. Your error is only on the fourth line here, but the traceback say `line 65`

Comment: I did this in line 54... X_combined_std = np.vstack((X_train_std, X_test_std))

Comment: We can't see line numbers. Please [edit] your question

Comment: @cricket_007 I edited it, check now please.

Comment: Your variable still isn't defined. You made a function plot_decision_regions, and called it with an undefined X parameter

Comment: Ok, Spyder is going a bit crazy with your code. You have a lot of undefined variables. What you define inside the function is gone once you leave the indentation of the function.

Comment: Okay guys, I am checking right now.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code before you run plot_decision_region. It should work.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sc = StandardScaler()    
sc.fit(X_train)    

X_train_std = sc.transform(X_train)    
X_test_std = sc.transform(X_test)    
X_combined_std = np.vstack((X_train_std, X_test_std))    
y_combined = np.hstack((y_train, y_test))
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not standraize `X-train` data set, do that first.

```
sc = StandardScaler()

sc.fit(X_train)

X_train_std = sc.transform(X_train)

X_test_std = sc.transform(X_test)
```

Comment: Do you mean "standardize"?

Answer (score -1):

It's because you have not defined `X_combined_std` or `y_combined`. if you have implemented it some where else, make sure to run that part of the code before this code executes.

Comment: ... pretty sure this doesn't resolve the issue. See the comments under the question.

Comment: I fixed the issue. Now I am getting this error... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\qasim\Documents\python_machine_learning\scilearn.py", line 56, in <module>
    plot_decision_regions(X=X_combined_std, y = y_combined, classifier = ppn, test_idx = range(105,150))
  File "C:\Users\qasim\Documents\python_machine_learning\scilearn.py", line 47, in plot_decision_regions
    plt.scatter(X=X[y==cl,0], y = X[y == cl, 1], alpha = 0.8, c=cmap(idx), marker = markers[idx], label = cl)
TypeError: scatter() takes at least 2 arguments (4 given)
[Finished in 2.6s]. Can someone help?